# Sum of powers in multiple ways

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I came across this little tidbit in a book with no reference or extra explanation.
We have
$$1^n+6^n+8^n=2^n+4^n+9^n\qquad \forall 1\leq n\leq 2,$$
$$1^n+5^n+8^n+12^n=2^n+3^n+10^n+11^n\qquad \forall 1\leq n\leq 3,$$ and
$$1^n+5^n+8^n+12^n+18^n+19^n=2^n+3^n+9^n+13^n+16^n+20^n\qquad \forall 1\leq n\leq 4.$$

I have no idea how to search for this, and whatever I have tried has turned up empty. Does anyone know if this has a name of some kind? If this is a duplicate, I couldn't find it.

More specifically, and what I care about, can we continue this? In other words, for every $N$, do there exist distinct $a_1,\ldots,a_r,b_1,\ldots,b_r$ such that $\sum a_i^n=\sum b_i^n$ for all $1\leq n\leq N$?

Comment: The [mathworld article on Multigrade Equations](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultigradeEquation.html) may interest you. I found this name following a hunch of checking Richard Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*. See also their article on the [Prouchet-Tarry-Escott Problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prouhet-Tarry-EscottProblem.html).

Comment: That's the term I'm looking for! Looks like the Prouhet-Tarry-Escott Problem is more specifically what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you make this into an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: See _The Prouhet Tarry Escott Problem and the Thue Morse Sequence_  https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/joc/2016/0007/0001/JOC-2016-0007-0001-a005.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned into an answer and added more details on request.

This type of equations is called [Multigrade Equations](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultigradeEquation.html), or more specifically, the [Prouhet-Tarry-Escott Problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prouhet-Tarry-EscottProblem.html). (Links are to their respective MathWorld articles). [Six of a kind .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090795/six-of-a-kind/) contains some more discussion of this problem.

As to whether a solution exists for each $N$, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163369/polynomials-and-partitions/1215516#1215516) contains a constructive theorem by Tarry-Escott which proves the affirmative, with $r = 2^N$. Hence the interest in the problem is to find *ideal solutions*, where $r = M+1$ as they are minimal.